# Use of nor and or

Tags: grammar

my question is can the word "or" follow the word "never" in a sentence - see below example.

"I have never wished you to hurt me or anyone..."

or should it be "I have never wished you to hurt me nor anyone"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In that sentence, use or. Either...or, neither...nor, and any other negative in most cases is better followed by or.